# "Stored procedure 'xxx' may be run only in unchained transaction mode." error when calling a procedure from a DataSource, in an EJB context

Tags: java, jboss, ejb-3.0, sybase

We have a Database in Sybase, which we access from a Java server.

Access to the DB was made directly through the Sybase driver, using `DriverManager`. It was working correctly, we were able to call our stored procedures.

Recently, we are migrating to an application server (on JBoss 5), and the calls to the database are now made through a JNDI connector, using a `DataSource`:

```
Properties ppt = new Properties();
ppt.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
ppt.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
ppt.put("java.naming.provider.url", "jdbc/sybase");

InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(ppt);
DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup(AConfig.getInstance().getDatasourceJndiName());

Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
```

*(The DataSource is configured using the basic settings, from the [JBoss example](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/SetUpASybaseDatasource))*

However, in this setting, several procedures are failing, with this error:

> "Stored procedure '******' may be run
>   only in unchained transaction mode."

or this kind, for other cases (with the failing command changing):

> TRUNCATE TABLE command not allowed
>   within multi-statement transaction

From what I found on Internet, it looks like something in the JBoss or the connector is opening a transaction itself, causing these errors. As such, the diverse solutions I could find for these particular problems are too localized, and it seems like a bigger issue.

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour (assuming that this is the actual problem)?

---

*My knowledge in this particular field is quite thin, this is new to me. As such, there are probably important details missing to this description. Please indicate me how I can improve this question, what details I can add, if necessary.*

Comment: What are you using for transaction management?  I assume you're initiating a txn from a stateless session bean?  This message usually occurs because of a third party setting an auto-commit property and/or the SET CHAINED setting on the DB

Comment: @karianna - the datasource is initialized in an init servlet, and the calls after are made from stateless beans indeed. I don't see though what can set these properties, which is why I assumed it was a setting in JBoss. I don't see any other "third party" in this context.

Comment: I would strongly recommend altering your code/architecture so that it can utilise the power of JBoss's connection pooling, data sources etc.  The actual code change will be quite small (it's still a JNDI lookup) and you'll be able to define whether you are using 2-phase XA, local or no transaction datasources (you define those in the *-ds.xml file).  See http://community.jboss.org/wiki/configdatasources for a starting point.

You probably also then need to (via EJB3 annotations I'm guessing) hook into Jboss's Txn manager.

Comment: @karianna - you are pointing me in the correct direction, thank you. Indeed, a part of the problem is that this is about porting an existing application, with a lot of business code in procedures. Transactions are currently managed in the procedures directly, which is why using local-tx is not appropriate, it conflicts with it. Switching to no-tx (for now, at least), seems to go in the correct direction, but some problems remain. I will update when I will have something more concrete to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not correct.

Certainly look at the bigger picture.  But there is an even bigger picture still.

Application server or not, is not the problem.  Settings in JBoss vs the previous app (Java) server is the problem.  Your coders have correctly ensured that their stored procs execute true transactions, and they are protected from subversion by outside entities (*any* calling stored proc or app server).  If they have done that, then those sprocs will run from *any* app server.

"Refactoring" is for the MS world, it is not required at all in the Sybase or Relational world.  If you change the sprocs to remove the tight transaction control, the business will suffer: loss of data integrity; loss of referential integrity; lost updates; duplicate transactions; etc.  If you are going to subvert the sprocs, or remove transaction control (as opposed to "refactor"), be warned that the consequence is enormous.

Clearly, JBoss is defaulting to either AUTOCOMMIT or SET CHAINED ON (because many people do not write true transactions, and these are the defaults for MS SQL ), and your previous Java (app) server did not do that.

Second, ODBC is very slow compared with a direct connection, so if you have not felt it yet, be aware that you will, very soon.  Datasources aren't "implemented", they are merely configured (takes a few minutes).  They use ODBC or JDBC.  It is a FAT layer between, and places a small buffer between, the program and the database, and of course gives up all the control that you had and enjoyed before, when you had the native connection.  I have seen it as much as twelve *times* slower.

Third, didn't anyone check JBoss out (a) before choosing it, for Sybase native connectivity (as opposed to generic, MS oriented), (b) during implementation and (c) during testing ?

If your connections are the problem, certainly, then just deal with the connection problem, and implement connection pooling (Java and Sybase have libraries for that), rather than reducing the quality and performance of your app, as well as the Consistency (that's the C in ACID) of the database.

EAServer (Sybase) and WebShpere (IBM) have no such problems; they perform connection pooling; and they use native connection to ASE (no ODBC or JDBC required).

Comment: Thank you for this very complete description. We actually had connection pooling implemented in Java, working correctly, in the existing application. As I said in my answer, we are back to using it, even in the AS context. It is based on Sybase drivers, so we will probably just keep using it, as you suggest a performance issue that would occur with this datasource from JBoss. Your answer is the most descriptive for my question, I will switch the "accepted" tick for it. Thank you, again!

Comment: `AUTOCOMMIT` is the same thing as `SET CHAINED OFF` and is the *opposite* of `SET CHAINED ON` so your statement "JBoss is defaulting to either AUTOCOMMIT or SET CHAINED ON` is confusing. I think you should consistently use either autocommit terminology ("autocommit" / "not autocommit") or chained terminology ("chained off" / "chained on" respectively)

Answer (score 9):

Apparently in Sybase stored procedures are created to run either in chained or unchained mode.

If you are getting this error it means your SP was created as Unchained. This Java line `conn.setAutoCommit(false);` is translated to "set chained on".

You can run this Sybase SP to list the transaction mode of all your SP's in your DB:

```
sp_procxmode
```

So you need to invoke your SP on the unchained mode and explicitly use, create transaction, commit transaction and rollback transaction.

For instance:

```
insert into publishers 
    values ("9906", null, null, null)
begin transaction
delete from publishers where pub_id = "9906"
rollback transaction
```

[Refer this link.](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/sqlug/@Generic__BookTextView/53713;pt=53001)

Answer (score 1):

This might help: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=49398, 'Holly' appears to have solved the problem

Comment: Thank you for your help, you gave me the pointers to find out the real problem, which was bigger than these messages.